# How do I get an SVG parser to render a single group element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I have an SVG document representing a deck of cards. Each card is uniquely group and named (ie 3_hearts). Now I want to be able to render one of those cards to the canvas. This stackoverflow user was in the same situation but in python: [How do I render *parts* of a svg file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321155/how-do-i-render-parts-of-a-svg-file)

I'm using a library called http://code.google.com/p/canvg/ which provides an interface to render SVG directly to canvas in the most desirable way possible:

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawSvg(SVG_XML_OR_PATH_TO_SVG, dx, dy, dw, dh);
```

The canvg constructor takes a svg string, url to svg file, or xml document.

Now, how am I going to get canvg to render just one of the cards? :/ Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you should be able to use an [SVG view specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) for this, something along these lines:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,200,200); }
img.src = "some.svg#svgView(viewBox(50,20,200,400))";
```

The svgView fragment syntax can select which part of the svg you want to render. Here is an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/reference-img-multi-view.html) (not using <canvas>, but just for the <img> element). Note however that some browsers haven't implemented this yet.

Comment: I've looked into the view specification and it is probably the viable solution. I couldn't get that example to work in Chrome or FF but I'll keep experimenting. Thanks

Comment: @LoneWolf - on non supporting browsers, you won't be able to get that to work, no matter what you'll do. i vote against this solution, as `svgView` is not yet adopted as a standard.

Comment: having that said, i can't wait for it to be adopted, as it makes SVG traverses a lot easier.

Comment: My project is going to containing hundreds of items, I was planning to put them into a couple of SVGs and use the DOM to access the ones I wanted. I am not even considering a file per entity. How would you guys handle this?

Comment: Am I able to change the height, width and view box of the root svg node to capture parts of the SVG? id rather be able to have an interface though though like svg.getGroup("ace_spades");

Comment: nice one, +1 on the innovation. (saw this during my "old answers revisited" private mission)