# How to draw a SVG src as image in GTK3 and python?

Tags: python, svg, gtk3

My code looks like this :

```
img = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="50" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <circle stroke-width="3" stroke="#1a1a1a" fill="#dfdbd2" r="16" cy="25" cx="25"/>
  <path stroke-width="0" fill="#1a1a1a" d="m25,9a16,16 0 0 0 0,32l0,-1.5a18,18 0 0 0 0,-29l0,-1.5z"/>
 </g>
</svg>'''
```

How can I display it in gtk3 window as image so i can use this?

```
    Image=Gtk.Image()
    Image.set_from_pixbuf(img)
```

and excuse me for my bad english :)

Comment: Try adapting the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321155/how-do-i-render-parts-of-a-svg-file) - it looks like you'll want to investigate the [rsvg library](http://developer.gnome.org/rsvg/stable/).

Comment: But I cant use it with Gtk3, Gtk3 is dynamic and Rsvg is static

Comment: I don't see why not, I have some code that loads an svg via `rsvg` into a `Gtk3.DrawingArea`. It becomes a fixed size, but that should be easy to deal with within the Cairo Context of the DrawingArea. If that's not what you're looking for, then could you explain a little further what really is the problem.

Comment: I want to draw a svg image in gtk from its XML source, not from a svg file, I can do this easy in PyQT.

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452797/draw-a-svg-image-in-gtk3-from-svg-source-in-python/19462187#19462187