# Draw a SVG image in GTK3 from SVG source in python

Tags: python, svg, gtk

As I can do it easily in PyQt like this:

```
img = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="50" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
   <circle stroke-width="3" stroke="#1a1a1a" fill="#dfdbd2" r="16" cy="25" cx="25"/>
   <path stroke-width="0" fill="#1a1a1a" d="m25,9a16,16 0 0 0 0,32l0,-1.5a18,18 0 0 0 0,-29l0,-1.5z"/>
 </g>
</svg>'''
image = QtCore.QByteArray(img)
self.svgwidget.load(image)
```

How can I do this in Gtk? any ideas? :) thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for bad english :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
stream = Gio.MemoryInputStream.new_from_bytes(GLib.Bytes.new(img))
pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_stream(stream, None)
self.svgwidget = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
```

Or use the rsvg library if you don't mind an extra dependency and want to do fancy stuff with the SVG once you've loaded it:

```
svg = Rsvg.Handle.new_from_data(img)
pixbuf = svg.get_pixbuf()
svgwidget = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
```

Answer (score 16):

For anyone who wants to load and scale a SVG image using Gtk 3 and Python (while preserving the SVG image quality!):

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf

path = "/path/to/image.svg"
width = -1
height = 128
preserve_aspect_ratio = True

pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(path, width, height, preserve_aspect_ratio)
image = Gtk.Image()
image.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
```

See also https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-File-Loading.html#gdk-pixbuf-new-from-file-at-scale